# how to use Matcher.replaceAll in java?

Tags: java, regex

i have a file which contains `"(*"` and `"*)"`. i want to remove everything between this two char sequences.
i used the following code but it didn't do anything with my string.

```
    String regex = "\\(\\*.*\\*\\)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    matcher.replaceAll("");
```

the 'input' is:

```
(* This program prints out a message. *)

program is

  begin
    write ("Hello, world!");
  end;
```

Comment: You expected it to remove something?

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right regex? You're compiling an empty string, which would definitely never match the contents of ( )

Comment: If the above is really all you do, you might want to use `String#replaceAll(String pattern, String replacement)` instead, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: exactly the regex is "\(\*.*\*\)", i forgot to put it in the question.

Comment: You can edit your question and put it in, but your regexp matches on *any number of opening parentheses*, then *any number of any number of any character*, then *one closing parenthesis*. Don't forget to quote your regexp-special chars, like `*`.

Comment: Are these OCaml comments you're replacing?  If so, the job is rather more complicated than it appears at first, because OCaml comments are nestable.  Also, what about things that *look* like comments but aren't, like the contents of this string literal: `"(*Hello, world!)*"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the return value of your matcher - it's `replaceAll` method returns the replaced String.

Additionally, use a regexp to match what you want to match, this time a parenthesized String. If you don't have some strange inputs, it may look like this:

```
String regex = "\\(\\*.*\\*\\)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
String result = matcher.replaceAll("(\\*\\*)");
System.out.println(result);
```

This regexp in fact captures the whole region from the first comment start to the last comment end, which would usually not be what you want. To let it match non-greedy (reluctantly), use this regexp: `\(\*.*?\*\)` (with doubled backslashes in Java.)

Comment: This answer is a good example of why not to answer too quickly ... I think the important solution (capture the result) was there in the first version. Later I added source showing how to remove the contents of string literals instead of comments, then reread the question and changed this. Then I remarked how this would (in a good program) remove about everything, thus the last addition. Bah.

Comment: @Hisoka: It's "Paŭlo" with an o, not an a, but I'm happy to hear this :-)

Comment: The argument to replaceAll is the replacement text, which should be "" like in the question - what is "(\\\*\\\*)"?